# Laravel DB Join Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have write a query for fetch every users his/her last organization name, but it's only return organization table last organization name. how can i develop this query for every users. 
Here is my Query.

```
 $org=DB::table('careers')
            ->join('users','careers.user_id','=','users.id')
            ->pluck('org_name')
            ->last();
    print_r($org);
```

Comment: show us your database schema, your model, relationship between tables

Comment: i didn't maintain eloquent relationships through model. i just use the **DB Facade**. relationship between users can have more than one careers history in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DB::raw` to get the records.

```
$org=DB::raw("SELECT users.name, t.org_name 
              FROM users JOIN (SELECT org_name 
                               FROM careers 
                               WHERE users.id = careers.user_id 
                               ORDER BY created_at DESC 
                               LIMIT 1) as t ON t.user_id = user.id");
```

Hope this could work.

Comment: how this query will fetch last organization name of a user??

Comment: When use get() instead of last(), it's show this error **Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(),**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `latest()` and `first()` method for getting last 1 record

```
$org=DB::table('careers')
        ->join('users','careers.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->latest()
        ->first()
        ->pluck('org_name');
```

OR

use `latest()` and `take()` method

```
$org=DB::table('careers')
        ->join('users','careers.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->latest()
        ->take(1)
        ->pluck('org_name');
```